# JSON Split - Place array text into li during interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My task is to take the 3 different color lists in the jsonObj and place them into a `<ul>`. They should only appear one at a time, every second. For the sake of the fiddle, I put it to every 5 seconds.

I haven't gotten to the 2nd or 3rd list of colors yet because while I can list out my 1st color list, they're appending outside of the listItem I've created for them. The code it spits it is:

```js
var jsonObj = '{"one":["red","green","blue"], "two":["red","green","blue"], "three":["orange","purple","hotpink"]}',
  object = JSON.parse(jsonObj),
  cOne = object.one,
  cTwo = object.two,
  cThree = object.three,
  i = 0,
  timer;

$('body').append('<ul/>');

timer = setInterval(function() {

  $.each(cOne, function() {
    var list = $('body ul'),
      listItem = $(list).append('<li>'),
      html = $(listItem).append(cOne[i]);

    if (i < cOne.length) {
      i++;
      $(cOne[i]).split("");
      list.append(html);

    } else if (i = cOne.length) {
      i = 0;
    }

  });

}, 5 * 1000);

timer;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also available at https://jsfiddle.net/ep76ba3u/

What it does:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
"red"
<li></li>
"blue"
</ul>
```

What it should look like:

```
<ul>
<li>red</li>
<li>blue</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried rearranging it all. I've tried using wrap, innerWrap. I've tried just using text() and a few other methods. I started working on it at 3am and its 5am now... brain is fried. Any idea how to get this moving is appreciated.

Comment: You are not paying attention to the errors that pile up in your browser's console.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/ep76ba3u/2/

Comment: It is not totally clear if you wish this to work like a stoplight - changing the "color" names in place or appending NEW items as you process (which would be a LOT of new elements over a short period  given the 1 second cycle).  Can you clarify?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - not like a spotlight. each name of the color takes on the style of that color as it appears. so per second, each LI appears. whatever color is in that LI, that LI should have that color as a style. So when 'red' shows up, it should be the color red as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel compelled to put in an answer which should perform better by cache of the jQuery objects and processes the objects and each color in them, hitting DOM once for each color.

```
var jsonObj = '{"one":["red","green","blue"], "two":["red","cyan","darkblue"], "three":["orange","purple","hotpink"]}',
  objects = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

// set timer values
var basetime = 1000;
var delaytime = basetime;
// cache the ul list
var myul = $('<ul/>').appendTo('body');
//process outer objects
$.each(objects, function(key, item) {
  // process color array held in item
  $.each(item, function(index, color) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('<li/>').text(color).css('color', color).appendTo(myul);
    }, delaytime);
    delaytime = delaytime + basetime;
  });
});
```

Test it out here https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/yb1w3o73/

Comment: Note  just to be clear it MIGHT be better if you created the node with all the children hidden, hit the DOM once to append it THEN put the timer around a function to display each in turn (change from hidden to shown, several ways to do that but class manipulation would be best most likely)

Answer (score 1):

You can not append partial html, that's why this `$(list).append('<li>')` is immediately closing the `<li>`.

And you should not modify the markup in a loop. It's obnoxious and unperformant.

Check out this approach to your code:

```js
var jsonObj = '{"one":["red","green","blue"], "two":["red","green","blue"], "three":["orange","purple","hotpink"]}',
  object = JSON.parse(jsonObj),
  iteration = 0,
  timer;

$('body').append('<div id=container>');

//a few utilities, because I don't want to repeat myself all over the place:
var string = value => value == null ? "" : String(value);
var wrapInNode = nodeName => value => `<${nodeName}>${ string(value) }</${nodeName}>`;

//here I create a few utility-methods that will build my markup:
var li = wrapInNode('li');
var ul = wrapInNode('ul');
var header = wrapInNode('h4');

timer = setInterval(function() {
  //building the complete markup and adding it at once
  var blocks = [],
    //how many rows should I show in this iteration
    numRowsLeft = ++iteration,
    //getting this result is just a nice sideeffect of using `every()` instead of `forEach()` 
    //to short-curcuit the loop
    done = Object.keys(object)
    .every(function(key) {
      //this line makes the title to be added with as a distinct iteration and not with the first item, 
      //check out what happens when you remove it
      --numRowsLeft;

      var rows = object[key]
        //shorten the Array to numRowsLeft, if necessary
        .slice(0, numRowsLeft)
        //wrap each item in a li-node with my predefined utility-function
        .map(li);

      numRowsLeft -= rows.length;

      //building the markup for this block
      blocks.push(header(key) + ul(rows.join("")));

      //here I'm short circuiting the loop. to stop processing the other keys on Object
      return numRowsLeft > 0;
    });

  $('#container').html(blocks.join(""));

  if (done) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And showing the header all the time while only adding the points:

```js
var jsonObj = '{"one":["red","green","blue"], "two":["red","green","blue"], "three":["orange","purple","hotpink"]}',
  object = JSON.parse(jsonObj),
  iteration = 0,
  timer;

$('body').append('<div id=container>');

var string = value => value == null ? "" : String(value);
var wrapInNode = nodeName => value => `<${nodeName}>${ string(value) }</${nodeName}>`;
var li = wrapInNode('li');
var ul = wrapInNode('ul');
var header = wrapInNode('h4');

timer = setInterval(function() {
  var numRowsLeft = ++iteration,
    blocks = Object.keys(object)
    .map(function(key) {
      var rows = object[key]
        .slice(0, numRowsLeft)
        .map(li);

      numRowsLeft -= rows.length;
      return markup = header(key) + ul(rows.join(""));
    });

  $('#container').html(blocks.join(""));

  // If I'd had room to show even more rows, then I' done
  if (numRowsLeft > 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not a bad solution overall, beginners will often need to research the arrow functions as the body of examples is less copious but that learning is OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonObj = '{"one":["red","green","blue"], "two":["red","green","blue"], "three":["orange","purple","hotpink"]}',
    object = JSON.parse(jsonObj),
cOne = object.one,
cTwo = object.two,
cThree = object.three,
i = 0,
timer;

$('body').append('<ul>');
var i = 0;
timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (i === cOne.length - 1) clearInterval(timer);

    $('body ul').append('<li>');
    $('body ul li').last().text(cOne[i]);
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This hits the DOM twice for each color appending the `li` and then the text, and searches the DOM twice for each color to find the `ul` and last `li` which is not the most efficient.

Comment: True, I just corrected the code. I would get the ul in a variable outside the interval.